# "Blank" pages in crystal reports with groups

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have 3 groups in my report, i'm trying to get page break between groups.

Results are fine except I get a blank page right before "Group 1" changes. The Page header has the same data as the next page except details section is blank.

After some searching, here are my current settings:

In the group expert, all 3 groups have "Keep Group Together" unchecked. In the section expert, all 3 groups have "New Page Before" checked and nothing else, no formulas either. Nothing checked in Group Footer.

What are my settings suppose to be so the I get a page break after each group?

Comment: can yu elaborate on page break? you are already getting a blank page...

Comment: But you want "a page break after each group" or "get a blank page right before 'Group 1' changes" ???

Comment: make sure that all fields that are using as a group have values

Comment: Why have New Page Before? Have a New Page after setting checked, and this will shift to new page, and add formula to not follow the logic in case last group item makes a group, make sense? If yes, I will post answer in detail.